# Use Sequelize add methods to insert multiple records

Tags: sequelize.js

When using `belongsToMany` associations, Sequelize attaches `add` methods to each of the implied models. For example, let's have the following diagram:

[image: Sample diagram]

This can be implemented using the following models in Sequelize:

```
// SHOP
const Shop = sequelize.define('Shop', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
});
Shop.associate = function(models) {
  Shop.belongsToMany(models.Employee, {through: 'ShopEmployee'});
};

// EMPLOYEES
const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  DOB: DataTypes.DATE
});
Employee.associate = function(models) {
  Employee.belongsToMany(models.Shop, {through: 'ShopEmployee'});
};

// N:M RELATIONSHIP TABLE
const ShopEmployee = sequelize.define('ShopEmployee', {
  schedule: DataTypes.STRING
});
```

Once we have some shops and employees created, we can add an employee to a shop using the auto-attached `addEmployee` method:

```
// 'shop' and 'employee' are model instances
shop.addEmployee(employee, { through: { schedule: '06:00-10:00' } })
```

Sequelize also generates a `addEmployees` method, which accepts an instance array or an array with the ids of the employees to add, so I could do:

```
// employees is an array of Employee instances
shop.addEmployees(employees);

shop.addEmployees([3, 4, 7, 8]);
```

This works fine, but it doesn't set the `schedule` attribute in the table `ShopEmployee`. Is there any way to specify one value per array item using `through`? This doesn't work:

```
shop.addEmployees([3, 4, 7, 8], { through: [ '6-10', '10-12', '12-15', '15-18' ] });
```

It adds correctly the 4 employees but assigns the same schedule ('6-10') to each.

Any suggestion? Thanks!